# What is the best way to add a smart banner to an Ionic2 application?

Tags: android, ios, ionic2, smartbanner

We have an Ionic2 application that runs on iOS, Android and web.  We would like to add a smart banner to the app that shows up when it is running on a mobile browser and prompts the user to open the mobile app.

There are some packages available for adding smart banners, but we are not sure how to integrate them into the Ionic application. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a Smart App Banner to your website, include the following meta tag in the head of each page where you’d like the banner to appear:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

More info: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

Comment: it wont work for any other browser than safari on IOS.